# delete branch on mercurial with no commits

Tags: mercurial

I created a branch on a mercurial repo but I realized that I don't need it and so far there's no commits to it. It's never been pushed so I was wondering if I can delete from history permantly without having to rebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I can do it so I'll just clone the repo again.

Answer (score 0):

New Solution:

Just use `hg up default --clean`. Works wonders.